# Stop using announcement banner for blog advertising

Tags: discussion, blog

I visited the homepage today and saw this:

> [image]

Where on the right, you have 2 links to the Overflow Blog, and on the top now,
you have another. I have posted about the sidebar before:

[Stop misusing the blog sidebar and restrict the announcements tag of the blog
to posts which are actually announcements of network-wide significance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344359)

but it seems the issue is getting worse, not better. Can we please stop using
Stack Overflow as an advertising platform for the Overflow Blog? I know the
blog exists. If I want to read the blog, I will visit the blog. For now, I have
added this to uBlock Origin filters:

```
stackoverflow.com###announcement-banner
```

hopefully I dont miss anything of actual significance.

Comment: I agree that it's annoying and I want it to stop too but if you're worried about missing something important, you could just close the banner (instead of blocking it) and it normally doesn't appear again (for the same "announcement").

Comment: Meh, just block it. Nothing important comes out of it anyway.

Comment: I feel like anything of actual importance would get pinned to the sidebar in one way or another anyways.

Comment: I find the blog post ads on the right okayish (and sometimes even worth a read), but the top banner is a bit annoying.

Comment: @41686d6564 banner shows up on every site. The dismissal kills it on _one_ site. You'll have to click it 114 times and counting if you want to go that way. At least I do assume it kills the banner on that site, not just one page, pending further observation.

Comment: It's not an advertising vehicle for the blog, it's for the podcast. Which nobody wants or needs, but someone at Stack Exchange Inc. thinks is really great, hence they're pushing it as hard as possible. And I'm amused that you think it would ever get better.

Comment: @John Well, that specific banner appeared on SO for me and once I closed it, it didn't appear on any other sites. I don't know if other users have had different experiences or if other banners may have different behavior though. BTW, I'm not trying to defend it. The first thing I said was that it's annoying.

Comment: New hypothesis: it dismisses the ad on all sites, but only briefly. Or maybe the dismissals get dismissed whenever there's an editorial change to the blog post.

Comment: @Ian Well, we can only hope. Those banners should really be reserved for the important stuff. Because they're not, I've developed a reflex to immediately close those banners without paying attention. It's almost the same as blocking it with an ad-blocker; which defies the (original) purpose of banners. The thing is this [has been requested before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338766/348196) though and they really don't seem to care :/

Comment: it's 1998 again! Next are gifs with skulls on fire!

Comment: Words can't express how tired I am (was) of having SO sea-lioning me about that blog. I've blocked all emails and removed the announcement box a long time ago. Disappointing to hear their still misusing it. And then I switch to main and there's an ugly grey banner for a podcast on the top. This isn't going to stop is it? I think I need a break.

Comment: I wish this post would be promoted via banner, so that more users can also tell what they think about SO blog, SO teams and all those ads on every page without a way to opt out.

Comment: "For now, I have added this.." You have quite a large tolerance. I blocked it after a couple of times when it became annoying. Sometimes, when using a different browser, I'm actually surprised how uninformative websites can be.

Comment: I can hardly remember when there was a **non** podcast notification in that bar...

Comment: For people with UblockOrigin who also want to *block it on left sidebar* (based on comment under https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344359) we can use selectors like `stackoverflow.com##.s-sidebarwidget--item:has(a[href*="stackoverflow.blog"])`
and `stackoverflow.com##.s-sidebarwidget--header:has(+ .s-sidebarwidget--item:has(a[href*="stackoverflow.blog"]))`. You can replace `stackoverflow.com##` with `*##` to make rule work on all domains, or you can specify your own list of domains like `stackoverflow.com,stackexchange.com##`.

Comment: Thanks for the UBlock value.  Second thing on Stack Overflow I have had to block.  (Though they will have to change the id of the banner to get me to see any announcements now...)

Comment: _Overflow Blog_ Quote: If everybody hates it, why is it still there?

Comment: To me this feels like part of the trend to become a social media platform. Which in my opinion is a horrible idea on its own.

Comment: @TaW "If everybody hates it, why is it still there?" Probably so that people can hate it a bit more.

Comment: I used to be slightly excited when I noticed the announcement banner. Now I just automatically assume it's some podcast and ignore it. I'm honestly surprised there isn't some modal "popup" yet to force it down my throat. Though maybe I shouldn't give certain people any ideas here..

Comment: Thank you for making this post - I just sincerely hope Stack Overflow listens to their community this time...

Comment: Why is this no longer in the Hot Meta Posts?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel It is for me.

Comment: @PiRocks It isn't for me: https://ibb.co/LrV982g

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: @Lino Can't blame caching for something that isn't cached.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This banner is already blocked by [Fanboy's Annoyance List](https://easylist.to/). If you want to hide it just add or enable Fanboy's Annoyance List in your ad blocking software.

Answer (score 259):

Given the level of soul-searching we used to put into every use of a banner (up to and including [building the entire bulletin system to stop one site from using banners to promote its own community](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/546/please-enable-community-promotion-ads-here/558#558)), seeing these is normally somewhat depressing.

...But not today. See, someone appears to have fat-fingered a URL, and so the banner is promoting a May 29th podcast instead of the September 29th podcast. **In other words: even the folks running the banner have become blind to what it actually displays.**

That's some delicious irony right there. Good for the blood!

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I checked and confirmed that the link is correct.

Comment: Ah well. That's what I get for assuming good intentions!

Comment: Wait so it's *intentionally* linking to a post from just over four months ago? Seems like that would have been better promoted... four months ago, no?

Comment: Does seem weird, but... There was a lot going on in May; [bunch of folks at SO got laid off](https://www.businessinsider.com/stack-overflow-reduces-workforce-furloughs-layoffs-2020-5) among other things. Maybe they felt it was in bad taste to promote it then and they're trying to catch up now? Or... maybe the interview with the wired editor from yesterday was just a dud and they needed something else to fill the slot. The ways of content marketers are inscrutable to mortals!

Comment: Necropodcasting.. blame coronavirus?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol actually, that makes perfect sense. After four months, you know for sure that the post did not get enough attention, so you start promoting it. In other four months, when it still did not get enough attention, the blog post itself will pop up over the stackoverflow page. And after yet another four, they will remove the close button if people keep clicking away too fast.

Answer (score 155):

Can't agree more.

Using the top banner for minor things like podcasts is bad for everyone:

1. It's bad for the innocent users who now have more unwanted noise in every page.
2. It's bad for the company because it causes users like me to ignore the top bar announcement **for good**. They'll ignore even the important messages, for which the banner was originally made.

Comment: I never got this podcast thing anyway. Sure, it has its audience, but to me all of them (either comedy, or about Formula 1, or about the site I visit for hours per day, or any subject really) just don't interest me. Why would I want to listen to some "coffee table chatter" for an hour, which is just people speaking their thoughts out loud, which I'm not a part of?

Comment: And don't get me started on that damn blog, which are just poorly-written advertorials where the comments are poorly moderated.

Comment: @CodeCaster well, I got nothing against the podcast itself and I respect the people involved, but as you said, it's not important enough to have such aggressive advertisement.

Comment: @CodeCaster "coffee table chatter" -- yes, exactly, well put. I would be very interested in listening to a well put together presentation on something that at least attempted to be informative, but the podcasts I saw from SO weren't really that. As for the blog I'm disappointed in that too, it really wasn't what I had in mind when I answered the survey saying I'd like articles; I think given SE's staff, somebody there should have the ability to write useful stuff and there's a lot they could write about, and they have a big platform, I think they're wasting it.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I can sometimes enjoy hearing people talk about something, but the one episode I listened to of the podcast mentioned an SO question about optimization / performance that I was familiar with and basically missed the point of the question, and IIRC basically mocked people for caring about performance (of their distorted idea of what the Q was about / at all).  So I had zero interest in hearing what they had to say about anything else.  So I gave it a try, and even if you were interested in coffee table chatter, I wouldn't recommend *that* group's chatter to you.

Comment: The trouble is, these are people who are really keen on pushing the "tech is cool", "look at me I'm a geek and I'm awesome" thing .. without actually knowing all that much about either of those things.

Comment: Another thing that I just thought of about the podcast, they tend to just touch on the "sizzle points" in the summary. A few times I saw something interesting in the summary only to find out that it was just mentioned very briefly, so I'd listen to the whole (rather long) thing only to find a really surface level coverage of what I hoped to learn more about. It reminds me more of those Youtube "reaction channel" accounts, like the podcast members are just reacting to the stuff I'm interested in, instead of publishing original work on it or really analyzing it.

Comment: @jrh it's basic marketing tactic, yeah. Annoying, but essential for the business. :/

Answer (score 70):

I hope whoever is posting these blog/podcast ads understands the effect that they have.  A lot of people (myself included) are significantly *less* likely to visit your blog or listen to your podcast when it's aggressively pushed like that.  Heavy advertising is often used to compensate for a poor quality product that can't sell itself, so a constant stream of banner ads instantly makes me think less of the item being advertised.  Plus, visiting the blog/podcast would mean that these annoying advertising methods appear to work and would thus encourage *more* of them.  That's certainly not the result anyone wants, so we make it a point to avoid the blog/podcast, even if it's something that we might have normally visited without the ads.

You'll get your podcast link in front of more people by simply adding a "latest podcast" entry to the bottom of the "blog" section in the yellow sidebar.  People won't just close/hide the banner, it's not going to get on people's nerves as much, and most importantly, you're not training people to ignore banners that might hold important, meaningful information.

Comment: I agree with your first point - Self promotion often makes me hate it more.

Comment: Same thing happens when I get presented with ads for games -- If the game looks interesting enough for me to download, I go find one of their competitors that wasn't annoying me with ads to play instead of the one presented. I have loads of podcasts I can be listening to, why listen to one that's annoying me?

Comment: I'd visit blogs like Coding Horror and Joel on Software all the time. They were promoted *somewhere* on SO, but it stuck. The ones promoted in the sidebar seem low quality, with little to say, so now that I've read a few of them and didn't like them, I avoid it altogether even if someone links it somewhere.

Comment: I skim almost every blog, some of made me concerned about conflict of interest on the writers (as in "what does the creator of X have to say about X"), some of them seemed like 1-sided ads, the technical opinion pieces seemed to be uncontroversial, vague, and lacking in any useful specifics. SE.SE is miles ahead of the blog in usefulness, for example, and they're not even paid to do it. For a company that allegedly understands devs, why aren't they making detailed oriented / technical articles for a skeptical audience that's probably read a thousand blogs?

Comment: Some of the other blogs make me wonder if SE even reads its own content on SE.SE, Law, and Workplace, because they tend to be better cited, more detailed, and devoid of spam (thanks to strict self promotion rules). If the blog is intended to be a frontend summary of SE, I honestly think it's missing the mark by quite a bit, a lot of those blog posts would've been downvoted, closed, and deleted if they were posted on a site that they were on topic on.

Comment: "I'm less likely to visit your blog if you advertise it" comes off as spiteful and boyish to me. You're clearly not alone in your view, but I **highly** doubt that they've seen *fewer* views on their blog/podcast after advertising it more.

Comment: @forresthopkinsa -  Not spiteful, just a desire to avoid doing something that might encourage behavior that comes across as annoying and/or harmful to the site.  They most likely see more views in total, but they need to be aware that the methods they're using are also turning away people.  Finding a promotion method that brings more views *without* turning away people would be a much better approach for all involved.

Answer (score 50):

My [ReduceClutter userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js) hides podcast announcements and clickbaity blog post titles in the sidebar.

Step 0 - Install a userscript manager browser extension:

- Recommended https://www.tampermonkey.net

Step 1 - Install/update userscript by clicking on this link:

- https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/ReduceClutter.user.js

---

Tested in Chrome, Windows 10, with Tampermonkey.

*[Report bugs for this userscript here](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/issues/new?template=bug_report.md)*

Comment: Where's the Profit step? :p

Comment: @IanKemp the one that profits here is the one who install the script.

Comment: @IanKemp You forgot the most important one: *Step. 2: ????*

Comment: Hum, 'ReduceClutter' Script doesn't seem to work (no Change as without) on PM v26.3.3 (but the whole SOF Site is also completely buggy in this (= my Default) Browser), nor FF v55.0.3, both with 'GreaseMonkey', and even 'GitHub' doesn't "like" FF55 anymore, ah-ah...! (Both Browsers are "old", but I need them for Web-Automation with iMacros...) No big deal though, I only installed the Script to "test" it as is..., I probably know how to modify it if I really wanted it to work in those 2 Browsers...

Answer (score 41):

I'd never had a preference on adblock plus vs ublock origin until I found all these handy ublock origin scripts cleaning up my SO experience. Thanks! I would've never discovered such a handy product if it wasn't for all the ads!

Answer (score 28):

I agree with you - I'd only like to see this used for major site changes. Otherwise, I can look at the sidebar myself.

Truthfully, I only look at the blog occasionally, but that's not driven by me not being aware of the content. I almost feel bad saying this, but I don't really find the majority of the topics all *that* interesting (unless it's something that impacts me a lot personally, like an announcement of major technical news or a very new technology that I haven't heard yet, such as the Nvidia purchase of ARM).

Deliberately using this to promote a 4-month-old blog post seems rather ridiculous; if that's what it's going to be used for now, this'll just become "noise." I feel a little bad about saying this too, but the topic wasn't particularly interesting to me regardless of how it was announced, and being more "in my face" about it didn't change that fact.

Answer (score 17):

Completely agree. That particular spot is the most prime of all real estate, with an eye catching background. And it is used to highlight content of very low relevance.

The blog is mostly random tech articles with tangential relevance to StackOverflow, or self-promotional stuff about StackOverflow the company.

Occasionally there's an article actually relevant to the community (ie, about a big product overhaul, or some data analysis) - those are fairly good, and worth promoting.

Comment: Even if it were important enough to promote in the banner, it's not even transcribed (or at least I couldn't find any transcription after searching for 10 minutes on the blog), so I  wouldn't know what the podcast actually contains.

Answer (score 7):

Surprising. I have seen this too and thought that this advertisement is present because of my less reputation. But It's not at all dependent on reputation and I completely agree with you. We will read or listen to that if we are actually interested. This should not be a platform for advertisement.

Answer (score 5):

My magic 8-ball says: Soon you will see a StackOverflow banner saying

> We won't stop pushing our podcast and you *will* [Listen Now!]

:-P

Comment: `[Listen Now!]` is not good enough. The podcast should probably start playing in the background with no buttons to stop it :-D

Answer (score -6):

We're missing a scapegoat for Stack Exchange in this discussion, so I'll take the hit today.

The banner doesn't bother me at all. In fact, due to an effect that's been noted on this site many times before, we're trained to scroll past banners anyway. If there was something really important on the banner, I'd miss it until the fourth or fifth scroll past -- which isn't a very long delay when you use the site several times a day.

I think the blog and podcast are cheery, and while I don't read or listen to them frequently, I quite appreciate SE's effort to sample and package different parts of the developer world.

Reading this discussion, one would think that this community is compulsively critical. Then again, I guess you don't get the most representative sample by browsing Meta.

Comment: The answer would be perfectly fine without the last paragraph, which needlessly dismiss other users without actually addressing the question.

Comment: I think the last paragraph, while not addressing the question, *is* addressing a peculiarity in the current state of the discussion which makes the consensus questionable.

Comment: Too bad. It ruins an otherwise healthy counterpoint, by adding unnecessary distraction and confrontation.

Comment: In case you didn't notice, there's a **dedicated** section on the sidebar for the blog posts/podcasts. The banner should be for _alerts_. And that's what people are criticizing.

Comment: Youre say essentially "well, Ive learned to ignore the banner, so its fine!" 1) not everyone can ignore the banner so easily 2) the banner **shouldnt be ignored**, whole the point is that its supposed to be for important stuff, not blog posts from months ago 3) Imagine the new user experience is bad in this regard, as they arent used to ignoring anything, and are bombarded with all this crap.