# What's the deal with the Deno banner?

Tags: discussion

The banner at the top of the page reads "What's the deal with Deno? We talk with a major contributor to find out. Listen now." and links to [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/29/podcast-239-brian-leruox-begin-aws-lambda-deno-rust-typescript).

It feels kind of spammy. There's already ad-like things on the left ("Free 30 day Teams trial") and on the right (actual ads). Must there be an ad-like thing on the top now, too? Is there not enough room in the "Overflow Blog" section that's already on the page, or is this somehow significantly different from all other blog content?

I wasted five seconds finding and clicking the close button just like I do with all those "This site uses cookies" annoying banners littering the internet, and here I'm wasting another five minutes complaining about it.

On a more positive note, Deno sounds kind of neat. So there's that.

[image: What's the deal with Deno? We talk with a major contributor to find out. Listen now.]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401664/stop-using-announcement-banner-for-blog-advertising

Comment: Thanks, @Taplar. I voted to close as dup of that question

Comment: @Taplar to make it easier for others to find it. Before I posted this question I searched for "Deno" and didn't find anything. Now I realize that search was too specific, but perhaps leaving this undeleted will help others

Comment: De-- no. Uh-uh. Nada.