# Can we please get rid of the "SO for teams" banner?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, site-ads

Please can we get rid of the *massive* teams banner at the top of the page?

Firstly, it takes up most of the screen real estate on a laptop, next up it comes back every time you refresh the page and -the cherry on top- I'm already subscribed, we already use SO for teams!

Why are you shoving this in my face repeatedly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I see this annoying Teams banner?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406812/why-do-i-see-this-annoying-teams-banner)

Comment: The only good thing about this is that it goes away for good after clicking the close icon. If it doesn't for you, there is probably another local storage / cookies mixup. I forgot to check how the dismissal pref is saved and now sadly fail to determine what the mechanism is. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: They appear to be using a `notice-tfb` cookie for non-logged in accounts.  No clue what they're doing for logged in accounts, killing that cookie doesn't make the banner come back for me.

Comment: @JeanneDark No... As I said, I click the cross, it disappears, I refresh the page and it reappears.