# How can we get rid of Stack Overflow for Teams advertising forever?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, advertising, banner

I'm asking the question that wasn't answered [in this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406812/14469685) - *how can we get rid of all future banners, popups, links, ads, etc. for Stack Overflow for Teams (SOFT)?*

A few occasional ads are fine, but I would think that if someone *really* doesn't want Stack Overflow for Teams, then they shouldn't have to constantly be shown, "Hey, do you want SO for Teams?  It has all of these features!".

Suggestions from the other question:

- From [Kevin B](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406812/406817/#comment837025_406812): Make a specific className for all SOFT banners, popups, links, etc. so that we can remove them all at one time.
- From [Lakshya Raj](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406817/14469685) (me): Add a button on our profiles so that we can choose to never see SOFT popups, banners, links, etc. and a "Check back after: " button so that we can only see them after: 30 minutes, 1 hour, 2 hours, 4 hours, ..., 1 day, 3 days, ..., forever.

Comment: but what if one day in the future you forget teams exists and need it, how would you ever find it without ads

Comment: @KevinB: Pretty sure that not *everything* should be blocked, just popups and banners that just add to the effect.  Maybe a once-in-a-while ad should be fine?  Let me edit the question.

Comment: in all seriousness, i don't think asking them to remove them entirely forever is... realistic. they're a business and and should be expected to advertise their own products on their own platforms, I just wish they would be more respectful about it. Take a step back and re-think what areas of the site will be used for ads and what areas will be used for announcements, and then stick to it with consistent reliable markup so that those of us who want to customize our experience can.

Comment: @KevinB:  It's a signal that really shouldn't be ignored.  Someone's not happy about being bombarded by those ads for this product that they're not using, and that's something that the teams responsible for the service should really think about.

Comment: @KevinB: But some people know, "I don't want SO for teams."  Many people from the other question say that they don't need SOFT and it's just a disturbing banner.  I understand that what you're saying is right, but there should be an option for people who just don't want this.

Comment: cont. With the way things are now, I can't be sure whether or not my block rule will block future site satisfaction surveys or new feature announcements for Q&A because the same sections are being used for both.

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/26/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/ *the car dealership example gave me a chuckle, given the recent banner ad*

Comment: "We don't accept rich media like animated ads (...)" @ this blog post: please see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406815/14469685) most upvoted about this recent banner ad.

Answer (score 1):

This might speak to an imbalance of how advertisements are displayed to users who have the [Reduce Ads privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads).

In short, by ticking this setting...

[image]

...you as an authenticated user will no longer see the banner adverts.  The side adverts are always still visible.

The interesting thing about this privilege is that it doesn't really state *what* kinds of adverts are being blocked or filtered out (e.g. what type of advertising you're immune to).

Some solutions/ways forward:

- Spell out what kinds of adverts would appear where.  If internal (e.g. Stack Exchange) ads exclusively appear at the side bar, then if nothing else, users know what to try and block.
- Allow for either a lower number or zero internal (Stack Exchange) adverts to be displayed when this reputation threshold is hit.
- Allow for a user to specify what kind of adverts they're interested in as a means to better target them.

Comment: I have reduce ads on and I still saw the banner...unless I am misunderstanding something here.

Comment: The strange thing is that for some time I saw the banner (~30 hours) and then it disappeared - and I even had reduce ads all of the time!

Comment: I assume the intent was that bit to be more of a feature request, than claiming that's the way things are now... more, the way it ought to be

Comment: So @10Rep that means that for the sake of this campaign, the banner isn't implemented as an advertisement.  Kind of a shame, really.